# pivoting table according to Paid of each months in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table:

[image]

I want to pivoting this table according to Paid of each month like:

**student_ID | Class_ID | Year | حمل |  ثور |  جوزا**

any help, please...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT student_ID, class_ID,year,month,sum(paid) as month_total
  FROM tablename 
  group by month 
)
PIVOT
(
  sum(month_total)
  FOR month in ('JAN','FEB',....,'DEC')
)
ORDER By student_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Do you know what version of MySQL OP use???  Your solution may not work at all for OP.